# Non-null alternative to Void (Java unit type)

Tags: java

I have a map-like type `SmurfMap<K, V>` which in certain contexts I use as a set-like `SmurfMap<K, Void>`.  Implementation details forbid the values of the map from being `null`, so I cannot actually use `Void` as a [unit type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type).  Are there any non-null alternatives to `Void` in the JCL or Guava?

Types considered and not yet rejected:

- new singleton enum `Unit`
- `Class<Void>`
- `TypeToken<Void>`
- `Object`

**EDIT** `SmurfMap<K, V>` does not implement `java.util.Map`.  The datastructure backing a `SmurfMap` is terabytes to petabytes in size.

Comment: Standard Java libraries use Boolean (`Set<T> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(Map<T, Boolean> map)`)

Comment: Is K actually an enum?

Comment: @Ordous Boolean seems odd.  What's the difference between a map which does not contain the key `"fish"` and a map where the key `"fish"` go to `false`?

Comment: @RobertCooper The value is never looked at, only the presence or absence of such. Hey, I didn't write `java.util`, don't blame me for quirky stuff there!

Comment: So you're asking what's a suitable way of iterating through the keys of `SmurfMap`, which doesn't implement `java.util.Map` and therefore no `keySet()` to rely on? FWIW `java.util.HashSet` is backed by `java.util.HashMap` and uses `private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();` as the value.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the values, don't use a map. Use a `Set`. It's a collection that contains no duplicate elements (by `equals` and `hashCode`) and has `O(1)` membership checking.

If the code is impossible to structure in a way that uses a set, and it must use a map*, then of these options I'd make a singleton `Unit` type. I'd pick this because as a map value, it does the best job communicating that the value is unused. A `Map<T, Boolean>` implies that the boolean-ness of the values matters and should be checked.

* This indicates a pretty nasty code smell, and you should examine your design more.

Comment: I think you have the situation backwards - seems the OP already has a custom `Map`, and doesn't want to duplicate the code into a almost-identical `Set`. (Same reason there are no `ConcurrentSet`s in Java). Hence this is not a question of "I want a set, what should I use? I've got a `Map`.", but rather "I've got this `Map`, I'd like to reuse the code as a `Set`, but without copy-pasting".

Comment: @Ordous I'm still answering the first question - if you have a map that you pass around, and the values are being used, there's no need to even ask the question because you just use map.contains. If you have a map and you never use the values, you shouldn't be using a map. If you have a map, never use the values, and can't replace it with a set, it's a code smell as I said and in that case I recommended the Unit singleton value. I think this pretty solidly answers all aspects of the question.

Comment: But then your answer collapses into "Use a `Unit` type!" with no argument or reason for it.

Comment: @Ordous I've updated my answer with my reasoning

Comment: @Ordous like the [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html)? or are you referring to that there is no ConcurrentSet interface?

Comment: @Ordous: `Hence this is not a question of "I want a set, what should I use? I've got a Map.", but rather "I've got this Map, I'd like to reuse the code as a Set, but without copy-pasting".`  And the answer is still valid: "don't do that."  This looks like a classic case of "when all you have is a hammer..."

Comment: `SmurfMap` does not extend java.util.Map.  It is a map-like abstraction over a petabyte sized data structure.

Comment: @MasonWheeler `ConcurrentSkipListSet<E>` is implemented on top of a `ConcurrentNavigableMap<E,Object>`, `HashSet<E>` is implemented on top of `HashMap<E, Object>`.  I'm doing something similar.  I'd like to avoid the weight of a custom `SmufSet<K>` interface if it's easy.

Comment: @RobertCooper It certainly doesn't seem like it would take more than 20-30 minutes to write such a thing. It's well worth the time spent simply communicating intent to other developers

Answer (score 3):

You said in the comments that "SmurfMap is a map-like abstraction over a petabyte sized data structure". That means that storage space should be a major concern.

Given that background, I would use a custom type with only one value, which serialises to zero bytes. Go through the SmurfMap implementation to make sure that that will actually result in the least amount of storage space needed.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, and constraining to JCL or Guava, what about `Optional<Void>`?
Void is uninhabitable, so that Optional is surely always empty.

In some of my projects I use `Tuple0` from javaslang, and others `Tuple0` from vavr. Given a 0 arity tuple is usually called `Unit`.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative techniques to consider:

- Use a type with the `Void` generic argument removed.  Instead of a `Callable<Void>`, use a `Runnable`.  Instead of a `SmurfMap<K, Void>`, use (or make) a `SmurfSet<K>`
- Modify the clients to be null-friendly.  For example, I know of no good alternative to `Future<Void>`.  Guava's [Futures.allAsList()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(java.lang.Iterable)) returns an unmodifiable wrapped `ArrayList`, not an `ImmutableList`, quite possibly in part because a the null-hostile `ImmutableList` would prevent the method from being called with `Future<Void>`s.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are proposing some concurrency-related classes in your own answer? If so, are they missing from your original question?

Comment: My question was "Non-null alternative to Void (Java unit type)".  I gave a specific case about a `SmurfMap`, but my question in general was about what to do you do when you'd like to use `Void` as a type parameter but you can't use null values.  `Callable`, `Runnable`, and `Future` were random examples to illustrate different workarounds.  The fact that they are all concurrency related was a coincidence (I could just as easily used `Supplier` or `Function` for examples).